Есть два класса. Как определить, является ли первый класс дочерним классом второго?
В методе родительского класса хочу определить взаимодействие объекта с другими объектами этого родительского класса и всеми его дочерними элементами. Можно ли как-то определить, является ли некоторый класс дочерним классом другого класса.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of ?

Это сиплюплюс. Тут на этапе проектирования понятно какой класс прилетит. В рантайме они не наследуются

Если этот ваш вопрос связан с предыдущим, то мне кажется, что вам лучше просто создать enum с возможными типами объекта и хранить его в базовом классе.

Без примеров кода непонятно, но есть такие варианты:

Принимать ссылку или указатель на родительский класс, тогда можно будет обрабатывать и потомков. Тут пригодятся виртуальные функции.

Сделать шаблонную функцию, и проверять наследование через std::is_base_of_v или std::derived_from (последний заодно проверяет, что родитель публичный и однозначный (т.е. нет двух родителей одного типа)). Саму эту проверку - вписать в requires.



по ссылке ж не определить тип потомка - это ж просто адрес в памяти. надо в класс поле добавлять... а если все равно смотреть это поле - нет смысла в "typeof"

@eri Во-первых, если дергать виртуальные функции, точный тип знать и не нужно. Во-вторых, если класс полиморфный (с виртуальными функциями), то есть dynamic_cast и typeid (а typeof в плюсАх нет).

typeof абстрактно)
